# Backlog hierarchy displays only temporarily then list is flat

Tags: azure-devops

When selecting the backlog, the hierarchy of feature > backlog item > task shows for just a second, then goes away and im left with just a "flat" list of work items.  What can I check?  Another team member does not have this issue when they view the backlog.  View parents is "on"

[ update ]
Looks like I had an active "filter" turned on and as soon as I removed everything from my filter, the hierarchy showed back up, for both epics, features and pbi's.

Comment: Which browser do you use?

Comment: Chrome, but I tested it in Firefox as well.  See update above

Comment: So the issue solved :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what Ive found is that if you have an active query in effect, the parent/child hierarchy will be flat.  Just clear the query filters to see the hierarchy again